# host and admin login failure after upgrade to DNN 7.4.2

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I am getting a very strange issue.
My DNN site was 7.0.0 Community, today i upgraded it to 7.4.2 Community.

The issue is, after upgrade i am able to login as normal user but not as supueruser (host) or as site admin. It is giving "Login Failed. Please remember that passwords are case sensitive."

If login is broken then login for normal user should also not work, but that is working.

Anyone has any idea, what could be wrong there or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this EXACT issue.  Spent over 5 hours trying to figure out what the issue was.  I figured that it had to do with the encryption key in the web.config file... nope.  I then used a script from here to recover my password: 
http://twentytech.net/dotnetnuke/recover-your-dotnetnuke-host-password/#comment-12157

It recovered what I knew the password to be.  I always used the Username-"Host" to login, and this was failing as password not recognized.  I then remembered that I had a setting to allow logging in by Username or E-mail.  I tried the E-mail that I used with the Host account and voila, I was in.  For some reason, using Host would not work, but using my e-mail with the Host account did work.  I really hope that this helps someone else. This must be an issue with 7.4.2

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to the db you can go into the asp.net membership tables and copy the password hash and key from the user that works to the host user.  then login with the same password and change the host one once logged in.

Its the aspnet_Membership table.  Copy the password and password salt fields to the user that can not log in from the user that can.  Then make sure they are not locked out.

That should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having this issue, I've noticed that when logging in with a username that doesn't match the case of the username stored in the database (e.g. Host vs host), DNN can't find the cached user. This leads to several issues, like not letting the user know that the user is locked out until the next time the cache is cleared. Going to file a bug report with DNN.